# Create log file with SQL statements for only one database

Tags: postgresql, configuration

I have two Postgres databases. Can I write in a log file SQL statements only for one of them?

Answer (score 5):

Carefully reading the [Error Reporting and Logging](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html) documentation, and specially, the section [When to Log](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-WHEN), you will find the following configuration parameters, that allows you *not to log anything*:

```
log_min_messages = 'PANIC'
```

You should add this parameter to your `postgresql.conf` file; and (most probably) restart the service.

For the **single database** whose info you want to log, connect to that database and execute:

```
ALTER DATABASE database_where_you_want_to_log
    SET log_min_messages = 'WARNING';  /* or whichever level you need */
```

This allows you to have one default (not to log anything) for most of your databases and one exception for a single one.